# Unable to display bottom tab navigator icons

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Here's the return from tabs function:

```
return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName='Main' 
        screenOptions = {
            ({ route }) => ({
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                  let iconName;
      
                  if (route.name === 'Main') {
                    iconName = focused ? 'md-home' : 'md-home-outline';
                  } 
                  else if (route.name === 'Team') {
                    iconName = focused ? 'md-people' : 'md-people-outline';
                  }
                  return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
                },
                tabBarActiveTintColor: 'tomato',
                tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
                tabBarShowLabel: false, 
              })
        }>
            <Tab.Screen 
            name="Main" component={Main} 
            options={{
            tabBarButton: props => (<TouchableOpacity {...props} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Main')} />),
            headerShown: false,
            }} 
            />
            <Tab.Screen 
            name="Team" component={Team} 
            options={{
            tabBarButton: props => (<TouchableOpacity {...props} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Team')} />),
            }} 
            />
            
          </Tab.Navigator>
  );
```

Even though I am following documentation I am unable to display icons. Please help me to display them..! And do comment on where did I went wrong!

Comment: Are you using expo vector-icons or react-native-vector-icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't go through the guidelines given in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ionicons), so adding those lines of code in particular files worked. :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).